# How do I prevent defining an alias in config/services.yaml for a bundle?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a bundle, which I like to be able to be injected into a controller for example. The only thing I want a user to do is register the bundle. And then be free to inject the service anywhere they like:

```php
namespace App\Bundles;

class MyService
{
    private $config;
    public function __construct(array $options)
    {
        $this->config= $options;
    }

    public function hello()
    {
        echo "Hello world";
    }
}
```

I have tried to define this line in config/services.yaml:

```
App\Bundles\MyService: '@bundle_service'
```

This seems to be working, but I don't want users to do this.

This is my Configuration class:

```php
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder("my_bundle");
        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('author')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode("name")->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

And the my_bundle config file, which is just a test so far:

```
my_bundle:
  author:
    name: "Name"
```

My Bundle extension class:

```php
class MyBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            new FileLocator(__DIR__ .'/../Resources/config')
        );

        $loader->load('services.yaml');

       $configuration = new Configuration();
       $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $container->setDefinition('bundle_service', new Definition(MyService::class, [$config]));
        $container->setAlias(MyService::class, 'bundle_service');
    }
}
```

My bundle class:

```php
class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        return new MyBundleExtension();
    }
}
```

What am I missing. Everything is working, except I have to define this line `App\Bundles\MyService: '@bundle_service'` in `config/services.yaml` which I don't want my users to do. In MyBundleExtension I have provided the right definition:

```php
        $container->setDefinition('bundle_service', new Definition(MyService::class, [$config]));
        $container->setAlias(MyService::class, 'bundle_service');
```

When I leave out the `config/services.yaml` code I get this error:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Bundles\MyService": argument "$options" of method "__construct()"
```

Comment: The problem is that your app seems to be trying to autowire your bundle services.  So even though your extension has made the correct container definitions, autowire is trying to make a new one.  Am I correct in assuming that your Bundles directory lives under src?  If so, adjust your services.yaml file to exclude the Bundles directory and see what happens.

Comment: You are correct, how do I exclude this?

Comment: You gave the correct answer, moved the bundles folder elsewehere and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Create service with variable

```
services:
    # ...

    App\Updates\SiteUpdateManager:
        arguments:
            $adminEmail: '%admin_email%'
```

Or

Construct your service with

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

class MessageGenerator
{
    private $params;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $parameterValue = $this->params->get('my_bundle.author.name');
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The last answer I get this error:
The parameter "my_bundle.author.name" must be defined. And the first answer must be defined in config/services.yaml? This still exposes details outside the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyBundleExtension extends Extension
{
        public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
        {
             $configuration = new Configuration();
             $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

             $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
             $loader->load('services.yml');

             $container->setParameter('my_bundle.author.name', $config['author']['name']);
        }
}
```

Next

Declare service in config/services.yaml

```
my_bundle.my_service.service:
    class: App\Bundles\MyService
    public: true
    arguments:
        - '%my_bundle.author.name%'
```